Is my light switch box grounded and how to use the ground wires properly
I'm attempting to install a smart light switch and I noticed the old one was not connected to the two bound up ground wires in the box. The box itself seems to be painted metal. I assume the smart light switch does need connected to those ground wires, but if that's the case how?


You've got a brown Bakelite, non metal, switch box that doesn't need to be grounded. The two cables coming into the box have bare copper grounds crimped together. The best way to connect a switch ground to the existing ones would be to cut off the crimp as close to the crimp as possible and use a wire nut to connect all three.

So I would need to get another copper wire to connect the switch to the other two grounds?

@Andrew  If your switch comes with wire pigtails, then the green wire from the switch just gets connected to the two bare copper wires in the box. If your switch jut has screw terminals, then you'll need to get a 6"  piece of #14 AWG copper wire with green insulation.

Alright thank you!
